# Nginx, auth_request with dynamic path param

Tags: nginx, auth-request

My web service has serveral urls like this:

```
POST /service
GET /service/a59aeaba-7f3f-4826-896a-aeb48e1db256
POST /service/a59aeaba-7f3f-4826-896a-aeb48e1db256/action1
POST /service/a59aeaba-7f3f-4826-896a-aeb48e1db256/action2
...
```

Also, I have different url that has authorization check, which will return code 200 if success and will return 401 if failed:

```
GET /service/auth/a59aeaba-7f3f-4826-896a-aeb48e1db256
```

Now there this uuid value inside path as parameter, which is dynamic value.

I don't know how to capture `/service/{uuid}/*` url and make `auth_request` to `/service/auth/{uuid}` then, after successful response continue to `/service/{uuid}`

Is it even possible to do this in Nginx?

Comment: What does it mean continue to /service/{uuid} ? You have ways of capturing the string and proxy_pass or redirect to service/auth/{uid}. I feel like it's possible to do it if you control the return code of /service/auth/{uuid}/ but it's a whole 3 proxy_pass and different configurations. Can you tell me what http code does auth return on successful auth and on non successful one?

Comment: @flaixman It will return 200 if success and 401 if fails

Comment: @Mr.D were you able to find a solution? I'm stuck in a similar situation where I need a capture group (regex) from within the location directive to use within proxy_pass. It works when there is no auth_request, but not when I use auth_request.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture it using regex.

```
location ~* ^/service/(?<uuid>.+)/ {
```

Now uuid is in named group, which you can refer later as ${uuid}

Comment: Is it possible to refer it from separate location that auth_request calls?

Comment: Assign it to global variable